# Using compare.linkage from R to compare two data frames and create pairs to input data

Tags: r, string-comparison, record-linkage

I'm trying to input some data in my dataset based in another one. However, to do this I need to compare several variables and each one has a weight. Also, I need to form pairs using the KEY variables, which are the id in my data.

I was trying to use `compare.linkage`, but I couldn't find a way to insert the weights that I want e.g 40% to `Age`, 40% to `CHBORN`, and 20% to `URBAN`.

```
Complete <- data.frame(KEY = c(001, 002, 003), AGE = c(35, 38, 45), CHBORN = c(2, 3, 4), URBAN = c(1, 2, 2))

incomplete <- data.frame(KEY = c(004, 005, 006), AGE = c(25, 38, 45), CHBORN = c(1, 2, 4), URBAN = c(2, 1, 1))

KEY_Pairs <- compare.linkage(incomplete, complete, blockfld = c(2, 3, 4), strcmp = TRUE, strcmpfun = levenshteinSim()) #I stopped here
```

I want to find a result similar to this:

```
KEY_incomplete KEY_complete Scores   
  004             001        0.95
```

Usually, I do this using the software FRIL from Emory University, but I'm trying to concentrate everything in `R`.

Best,

Tereza

Comment: what package is `compare.linkage` from?

Answer (score 0):

The package is RecordLinkage: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf